# Highlight all occurences of a word in Visual Studio editor like NotePad++

Tags: visual-studio-2008

when we select a word in NotePad++ it will highlight all other occurences of it too, EClipse does that too.  is there anything for VS2008Pro that can do the same? sometimes it is helpful to quickly see in what other places a variable is used, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I use Visual AssistX and it has this feature, along with better syntax highlighting and intellisense. It is, however, a commercial productivity tool, and using it for just that feature might be a bit of an overkill. But it has a 30 days trial period so you might try it.